# Continue running test run even if one assertion fails in nightwatch

Tags: nightwatch.js

How i can continue my test run in Nightwatch even if one assertion fails.
i have added below properties in Nightwatch.json
"end_session_on_fail": false,
    "skip_testcases_on_fail" : false

but still other test cases run is skipped. Can anyone let me know the solution
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should write in global.js an option

abortOnAssertionFailure: false,

Answer (score 2):

I used .verify instead of .assert in my script. This worked. Thanks all.